# JavaScript regex replace - remove everything that's not a +Number or -Number

Tags: javascript, regex, string, replace

I'm looking for a way to take a string like below:

```
let s = '@someone hello that was awesome +5. Rock on!';
```

and strip out absolutely everything except for the first `+` or `-` and the immediate following number, using regex. The result would be:

```
+5
```

Other examples:

```
let s = '!#$#$%#$%^%^     -3000absdf' //-3000
let s = 'you get a +1 and a -2000 for your efforts' //+1
let s = s = '+++++++++++++++17   .' //+17
```

Comment: Why don't you just match (non-globally) on `[+-]\d+`?

Comment: What does that look like?

Comment: I posted it as an answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of stripping the rest of the characters out, just match (non-globally) on `[+-]\d+`.

```js
let a = [
  '@someone hello that was awesome +5. Rock on!', //+5
  '!#$#$%#$%^%^     -3000absdf', //-3000
  'you get a +1 and a -2000 for your efforts', //+1
  '+++++++++++++++17   .' //+17
]
var r = /[+-]\d+/

a.forEach(function(s) {
  if(r.test(s)) console.log(s.match(r)[0])
})
```

Comment: Crap, deleted my comment on accident. This works just fine - didn't need it in an array but works just fine :)

Answer (score 1):

Just match globally, and then check if there is a match

```js
var regExp = /([+-]\d+)/;

var match = regExp.exec('asdfadf +233 asdfadf -23434');
var number = match && match[0];
console.log(number);

var match = regExp.exec('asdfadf34+233jkjkjk asdfadf -23434');
var number = match && match[0];
console.log(number);

var match = regExp.exec('asdfadjkjkjk asdfadf ty3434');
var number = match && match[0];
console.log(number);
```

Comment: Why do you have a plus after the sign? That's incorrect. For the last example it will return `+++++++++++++++17`. It should be `[+-]\d+`.